# ExpressJS pass variables to Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, steam-web-api

I have some text in the form of some JSON that I have been able to pull from Steam's Web API using my server written in ExpressJS/nodeJS. This JSON is stored in a variable.

What I am trying to do here is to basically take the JSON that I have stored in a variable, send it to my Angular and then display the data onto my page.

When I do, my console shows the raw HTML of the page.

Is there something that I am missing?

My node:

```
app.get('/steam.html', function(req, res){
  request.get(steam_api, function(error, steamResponse, steamBody) {

    var steamList = JSON.parse(steamBody);
    gameList = steamList["applist"]["apps"]; 

    res.json({gl: gameList});  

  });
});
```

My angular:

```
$http.get('steam.html').success(function(data){
    $scope.gameList = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
```

My steam.html

```
<body ng-app="gameSearch" ng-controller="gameSearchController">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="steam in gameList track by $index">
        <li>{{steam.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Edit: If it helps here's a screenshot of what I am seeing. As you will see I am getting a bunch of bullet points back but not the names of each game.

[Express JS passes bullet points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1z0d.jpg)

Edit 2: Another thing I should add for clarity is that I used some nodeJS code that I found on a blogpost from codepen as shown below (https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/how-do-i-use-the-steam-api-in-my-web-app):

```
app.get('/steam/game/:appid/achievements', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
    // Calculate the Steam API URL we want to use
    var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/' +
        'v2/?key=YOURSTEAMAPIKEYHERE&appid=' +
        httpRequest.params.appid;
    request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
        httpResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        httpResponse.send(steamHttpBody);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can You provide https://jsfiddle.net/ for your code snippet please.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ujo8k80e/    I should mention that steam_api as shown in my node is a link to a Steam API call which includes my Steam web API Key (which I cannot give out per the steam web API terms.

Comment: Update: In my HTML, I changed the contents of the li tag to just `<li>{{steam}}</li>` then each bullet point shows each character of my HTML. As such $scope.gameList is somehow picking up the raw HTML of steam.html instead of my JSON(stored in a variable in my NodeJS/expressJS server). Here's the imgur screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/jbnJMYQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's been no update on this question for a while I thought I would tell you all what I ended up doing. In my node I ended up grabbing the JSON from the Steam Web API and saving it in a JSON file.

In Angular I then did a $http.get on that JSON file and then built my links using the ng-href directive.